# Need help with python list manipulation

Tags: python, list

i have two seperate lists

```
list1 = ["Infantry","Tanks","Jets"]
list2 = [ 10, 20, 30]
```

so in reality, I have 10 Infantry, 20 Tanks and 30 Jets

I want to create a class so that in the end, I can call this:

```
for unit in units:
  print unit.amount
  print unit.name

#and it will produce:  
#  10 Infantry  
#  20 Tanks  
#  30 Jets
```

so the goal is to sort of combine list1 and list2 into a class that can be easily called.

been trying many combinations for the past 3 hrs, nothing good turned out :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should do it:

```
class Unit:
  """Very simple class to track a unit name, and an associated count."""
  def __init__(self, name, amount):
   self.name = name
   self.amount = amount

# Pre-existing lists of types and amounts.    
list1 = ["Infantry", "Tanks", "Jets"]
list2 = [ 10, 20, 30]

# Create a list of Unit objects, and initialize using
# pairs from the above lists.    
units = []
for a, b in zip(list1, list2):
  units.append(Unit(a, b))
```

Comment: list comprehension one is better

Answer (score 18):

```
class Unit(object):
  def __init__(self, amount, name):
    self.amount = amount
    self.name = name

units = [Unit(a, n) for (a, n) in zip(list2, list1)]
```

Answer (score 8):

```
from collections import namedtuple

Unit = namedtuple("Unit", "name, amount")
units = [Unit(*v) for v in zip(list1, list2)]

for unit in units:
  print "%4d %s" % (unit.amount, unit.name)
```

[Alex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2072936/need-help-with-python-list-manipulation/2073030#2073030) pointed out a few details before I could.

Comment: @Ignacio: which is a stable version available for over a year now.

Comment: There are still Enterprise Linux distro versions in place that run 2.5 or even 2.4, and I believe that observers should be aware of the version requirement, even if it doesn't end up disqualifying the solution regarding the OP.

Comment: Is it unreasonable to expect the OP to read the docs (which I should've linked) and be at least aware if their version is behind the majority of users?

Answer (score 5):

In Python 2.6, I'd recommend a [named tuple](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html?highlight=namedtuple#collections.namedtuple) -- less code than writing the simple class out and very frugal in memory use too:

```
import collections

Unit = collections.namedtuple('Unit', 'amount name')

units = [Unit(a, n) for a, n in zip(list2, list1)]
```

When a class has a fixed set of fields (doesn't need its instances to be "expandable" with new arbitrary fields per-instance) and no specific "behavior" (i.e., no specific methods necessary), consider using a named tuple type instead (alas, not available in Python 2.5 or earlier, if you're stuck with that;-).

Comment: What, I beat Alex Martelli to a Python answer? How did this happen? I think I need a minute to sober up and make sure it's not 2012 or 2038 yet.

Comment: @Roger, heh, yep -- I took the extra time to provide the link, to carefully point out the 2.6 dependency to avoid Ignacio's usual whining about it (which punctually arrived for yours;-), etc, so your answer arrived while mine was still "in-flight";-).

Answer (score 2):

How about a dictionary:

```
units = dict(zip(list1,list2))

for type,amount in units.iteritems():
    print amount,type
```

Endlessly expandable for additional information, and easily manipulated. If a basic type will do the job, think carefully about not using it.